# MovingAverage[] and Fit[] with data containing DateLists

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have data which has the following appearance: `data = {{DateList, Real}, ..., {DateList, Real}}`
It's easy to visualize the data by using `DateListPlot`. In addition to `DateListPlot`, I would also like to show a function which fits the data and the moving average of the data.

I hope I described the problem clear enough.

Comment: You can convert the dates to numbers using `AbsoluteTime`; `DateListPlot` will still work and you can also do the fit and other manipulations.

Comment: `DateListPlot` will actually render faster if you convert to absolute time beforehand (incl. timing for the conversion).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To fit a function and to calculate the moving average you need to convert your dates in absolute time using `AbsoluteTime[]`.

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2004"];
newdata = 
    Table[{AbsoluteTime[data[[i, 1]]], data[[i, 2]]}, {i, Length[data]}];
lm = LinearModelFit[newdata, x, x];
movAvg = MovingAverage[newdata, 200];
Show[DateListPlot[newdata],DateListPlot[movAvg, PlotStyle -> Red],
    Plot[lm[x], {x, Min[newdata[[All, 1]]], Max[newdata[[All, 1]]]}], 
    Frame -> True]
```

[image: DateListPlot with fit and moving average]

### Update

This update implements the comment by Mike Honeychurch. Note that the moving average can be computed by averaging runs of only odd *r* elements.

```
movAvgDoneRight = MovingAverage[newdata[[All, 2]], 201];
elementsToDrop = (Length[newdata] - Length[movAvgDoneRight]);
movAvgData = Transpose[{Drop[
    Drop[newdata[[All, 1]], elementsToDrop/2], -elementsToDrop/2], 
    movAvgDoneRight}];
Show[DateListPlot[newdata], DateListPlot[movAvgData, PlotStyle -> Red], 
    Plot[lm[x], {x, Min[newdata[[All, 1]]], Max[newdata[[All, 1]]]}], 
    Frame -> True]
```

[image: DateListPlot with fit and moving average]

Comment: Just a minor comment: You don't really need a table to get `newdata`. I find modifiying `data` in place using `data[[All, 1]] = AbsoluteTime /@ data[[All, 1]];` more elegant :) Otherwise +1

Comment: @Ajasja: ...unless you have to do something after plotting/fitting that needs the date lists as opposed to the absolute times.

Comment: I'd interpret moving average in this context as meaning just of the data -- not of the dates (times) as well.

Comment: Thx, exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Good point, I'm just wondering how would you solve this, since in this specific case data are only available for days in which the stock exchange was open.

Comment: @J.M. Well ofcourse. But then `newdata=data; newdata[[All, 1]] = AbsoluteTime /@ newdata[[All, 1]];` is still easier to read and probably faster.

Comment: @VLC trim the dates (times) and transpose with the averaged data.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch The example in `FinancialData[]` is thus conceptually wrong: `DateListPlot[
 MovingAverage[FinancialData["GE", "Jan. 1, 2000", "Value"], 
  100], {"Jan. 1, 2000", Automatic, "Day"}, Joined -> True]`

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use `TradingChart` or `InteractiveTradingChart`, which have a long list of statistical indicators :

```
InteractiveTradingChart[{"IBM", {"Jan. 1, 2004"}}]
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 0):

For data in the form { ..., {date_i, value_i}, ... } you should consider using [TimeSeries](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html).

For example:

```
data = FinancialData["IBM", "Jan. 1, 2015"];
```

Then:

```
ts = TimeSeries[data]
```

[image]

And then you can operate on the time series directly, with functions like MovingAverage, and DateListPlot:

```
newts = MovingAverage[ts, 5]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[ newts]
```

[image]